# Regular Expression: Splitting by whitespace while recognizing " " as a token

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm using Python. For the following text,

`foo boo " " cat`

I want to split by whitespaces, but `" "` should be a token.

`['foo', 'boo', '" "', 'cat']`

This is what I want, but not easy to do. My stupid approach is replacing `" "` with non-spaced symbol... But, I believe it is doable just using RE.

Answer (score 3):

Try shlex:

```
In [2]: import shlex

In [3]: string = 'foo boo " " cat'

In [4]: shlex.shlex(string)
Out[4]: <shlex.shlex at 0x7f3937aa7bd0>

In [5]: list(shlex.shlex(string))
Out[5]: ['foo', 'boo', '" "', 'cat']
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in console:

```
import re
txt = 'words words words " " words " words"'
split = re.split(' ^((?!" ").)*$', txt) #split on space not contained in double quotes
```

Comment: Really? I get `['words words words " " words " words"']` --in other words, the original string.  That's what you get when the regex doesn't match anything.  I think I know what you were trying for with the lookahead, but this isn't even close.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach.

```
>>> import re
...
>>> s = 'foo boo " " cat foo "  " foo'
>>> parts = re.findall(r'(?:"[^"]*"|\S+)', s)

['foo', 'boo', '" "', 'cat', 'foo', '"  "', 'foo']
```